# Route [admin/CountryController.store] not defined in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-routing

My `CountryController` is in admin folder which has `store` function.

`Web.php` is:-

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
Route::resource('country', 'admin\CountryController');});
```

HTML Code is:-

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin/CountryController.store') }}">
```

It's showing error:- `Route [admin/CountryController.store] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\happyvivah\resources\views\admin\country.blade.php)`

Comment: name of controller is "CountryController" that is in admin folder. then why only 'Country.store' ? and country.store is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 'php artisan route:list' command in CMD. it will show the name of all route. it will show route name 'country.store'.

so after replacing to route('admin/CountryController.store') with route('country.store') it will work.